# How can I search for a multiple line string in Microsoft Office?

Tags: microsoft-office, find-and-replace

I have this string in many places in my word document.

```
this is 
a
string 
   that spans
multiple lines
```

How do I find and replace this string in my MS Office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the line breaks are the same for every instance of the string, use Find and add the appropriate special formatting characters.

Open the Find and Replace window either from the Home tab, or by hitting Ctrl-H

Click the `More>>` button, then enter your string. Use the `Special` button to insert the appropriate formatting marks.

[image]

Comment: In addition, we can also use VBA to find and replace a multiple line string in Office. Here is a thread on this for your reference: [Find and replace multiple lines/paragraphs](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/find-and-replace-multiple-linesparagraphs/cdde2358-10cb-4858-bf02-31be5e5a0d00). You can use macro(VBA) to [find and highlight multiple items in a Word document at the same time](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/find-replace-multiple-items-word-document/).

Comment: I was hoping there was a way I could just paste in my lines, but this is probably best answer for now.